# Como obter o valor que sai usando o select2 em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Tenho um select2 que usa essa lib (https://select2.org/).
Preciso pegar exatamente o valor que sai do select quando o atributo *multiple* do select estiver sendo usado (não o array, mas sim o valor que sai). Antecipadamente, agradeço.

Abaixo, o trecho do código:

```js
$('#mySelect2').select2();
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function(evt) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('#mySelect2').on('select2:unselecting', function(evt) {
  console.log('Teste', $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" style="width:100%;" multiple id="mySelect2">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Faça um log no seu `evt` para visualizar a estrutura do evento. o elemento clicado está em `evt.params.args.data.element`, logo o valor do elemento removido do select está em `evt.params.args.data.element.value`.

Comment: Obrigado, embora sua solução não resolva o problema, abriu um caminho para a solução do problema. Em breve, postarei aqui a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o André falou, usando o atributo data do atributo params de evt, eu consigo obter o value do elemento removido.

O segredo é usar o evento **unselect**.

Abaixo, o trecho do código

```js
$('#mySelect2').select2();

// Aqui está a solução
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:unselect', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.params.data);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" style="width:100%;" multiple id="mySelect2">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```